# Finding the number of nodes in 2-3 tree while left sub-tree of the root has 3 children,right sub-tree of the root has 2 children

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, 2-3-tree

Suppose there is a 2-3 tree with n nodes.

Each node in the left sub-tree of the root has 3 children. (except the leaves).

Each node in the right sub-tree of the root has 2 children. (except the leaves).

How am I supposed to find how many nodes exist in the right/left sub-tree of the root?

Denote n':= nodes number in the right root sub-tree.

Then,Nodes number in the  left root sub-tree is (n-1)-n'.

How am I supposed to find n' (to write n' as an expression of n)?

I am a little bit confused.

Thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let the total height of the tree be *h*. Since it's a 2-3 tree, both the left and right subtree have heigth *h*−1. The number of nodes in the right subtree is 2^*h* − 1, and the number of nodes in the left subtree is [(3^*h* − 1)/2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7Bh-1%7D%203%5Ei). Beyond that, I don't know anything really interesting to say. The quotient *n*ʹ / *n* doesn't come out very pretty, but it approaches zero quite quickly as *h* increases.